# Handling rotation in iOS 6 from a static cell table view controller

Tags: objective-c, rotation, ios6, xcode4.5

Im presenting a video clip with  `MPMoviePlayerViewController`  from a static cell in a tabelview controller.  In my destination view controller for the video clip I added:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

To my view controller, but as I understand it I need to add this to my presenting navigation controller which is a `UITableViewController` in my case.  Problem is I only have a .h file which I cant edit as i dont have permission apparently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the `.m` file of your view controller you will need to subclass it.